# Como substituir um atributo de um trecho de HTML que está como string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma variável onde contém vários códigos HTML. Está variável já está montada, o que tenho que fazer é substituir um atributo que está em uma div filho `(tabindex)`. Existe alguma função onde posso alterar esta variável, sem precisar dar um each.

Dentro dessa variável tenho 2 tabindex, no qual tenho que alterar.

```
var div = '
<div class="teste">
    Meu teste
    <div class="filho" tabindex="1">
       Div filho
       <input type="text" class="search" tabindex="2" />
    </div>
</div>';

ex:
.after(function(){
  return $(div)....attr("tabindex","10");
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converta a string em um elemento do DOM, que você pode atravessar normalmente:

```
var teste = $(div);
teste.find('.filho').attr('tabindex', 10);
teste.find('.search').attr('tabindex', 20);

// Depois você pode usar o nó criado normalmente:
elemento.after(teste);
```

Comment: Eu estava erradno pois não coloca $(div) em uma váriavel...  Obrigado.. ATT